# Tosefta vs Talmud in Halacha

Tags: talmud-gemara, halacha-theory, talmudic-methodology, tosefta, chiddush-talmudic-principle

If the tosefta contradicts the Gemara/Talmud (either Jerusalem or Babylonian), which is more authoritative in Halacha?

Comment: Do you mean [relative to Mishna](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114426/status-of-tosefta)?

Comment: No I mean if the tosefta brings an opinion contradictory to the ruling of the Gemara, do we follow the tosefta or Gemara @shmosel

Comment: I believe we usually follow the gemara whatever the contradictory earlier source is.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Peah.2.4.10

Comment: Tosefta was taught by the tannaim, like the mishna. The gemara wouldn't contradict a tanna unless it was siding with another tanna or correcting an error.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are describing? Very often the gemara is applying a Mishnah, so if the Gemara says something that's an application of the Mishnah presumably that would trump a contradictory pshat in the tosefta. If the mishnah was silent and the Gemara made amoraic statements that appear to contradict a tosefta, then I suppose that would be a kashya on the Gemara, but I would be surprised if that lead to a psak halachah against the gemara.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. It's like asking who we follow if a pasuk contradicts a mishna. The latter is the definitive interpretation of the former; if you see a contradiction you're misunderstanding one or the other.

Comment: @Avraham in my case the Mishnah is silent and the Gemara gives a P’sak which contradicts a tosefta

Comment: But what's the gemara based on? Even if it isn't b'ferush in the mishnah many gemaras are interpreting the mishnah. My basic instinct is like @shmosel, though I could imagine there are places where stiras and kashyas arise.

Comment: If there's a specific contradiction you're trying to resolve, why not ask about it specifically?

Comment: [This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/114508/27180) might answer the question about the authority of the Tosefta over the Mishnah and/or Gemara.

Comment: see also brachot 31a רב אשי עביד כברייתא and comentaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to Yad Malachi, [כללי הרמב"ם אות ט](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32532&st=&pgnum=15), where this topic is discussed. His conclusion is that not only is the Gemara granted precedence over the Tosefta, but we also do not accord authority to a Tosefta that lacks mention in the Gemara. His possible explanation is that before they made the Talmud they determined which Breisos were reliable.

> כלל גדול בידינו, שכל תוספתא או ברייתא שלא הוזכרה בגמרא משבשתא היא, דמסתמא כיון שרצו חכמי ישראל לחבר התלמוד, חקרו ודרשו בכל הספרים, וביררו אותם שהם בני סמכא דווקא

See the Yad Malchi כללי שני התלמודים אות ג regarding Tosefta vs Yerushalmi.

Comment: It's a little hard to read. Any chance you could quote the relevant parts?

Comment: whats כללי שני התלמודים אות ג

Comment: So it's not that the tosefta lacks authority or that the gemara has precedence, it's that we don't consider it authoritative if wasn't referenced by the gemara.